# Django Rest - Create User Password Hash

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to hash password, once created User and I'm using `Django Rest`. However i got an errors when trying to create it.

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
    ]
}
```

**`My UserSerializer`**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'active',
                  'admin', 'date_joined', 'password', 'partner']
```

**`My ModelViewset`**

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(
            user, make_password(request.data['password']))
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
        # return HttpResponse(user)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: add your `UserSerializer` class as well as the payload that you have used in the POST request.

Comment: also, why do you need to hash a password *here*? I don't see any ***user creation action*** in your given code

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I update my question, Pls Check it..

Comment: @ArakkalAbu my password is not hashing, when create new user. So, i want to `Override` my `UserViewSet`

Comment: override the `create()` method of ***serializer class***, which if more DRF way

Comment: @ArakkalAbu sorry, but i dont catch what u mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ahhhhhh I found my answer xD...**

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # Hash password but passwords are not required
        if ('password' in self.request.data):
            password = make_password(self.request.data['password'])
            serializer.save(password=password)
        else:
            serializer.save()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        # Hash password but passwords are not required
        if ('password' in self.request.data):
            password = make_password(self.request.data['password'])
            serializer.save(password=password)
        else:
            serializer.save()
```

Comment: this worked for me. i wonder how it looks like on serializer level.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request.data['password'] = make_password(self.request.data['password'])
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'message': 'Usuario creado correctamente!'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).